# Graphics2D text - font size change causes shift on X axis

Tags: java, fonts, bufferedimage, graphics2d

When writing text** to a `Graphics2D` object, I'm finding that the x position of the text changes when I change the size of the font.  As the size increases, the x position increases.  This happens no matter what method I use to write the text: `drawString`, `fill` or `draw` with a `GlyphVector`, or `drawGlyphVector`.

** both the beginning character of the text and the font type change this behavior: Sans Serif fonts, where the beginning character's left-most stroke is a vertical line (P, H, L, E, etc...) are the most affected.  If the font is Serif and/or the beginning character's left-most stroke is not vertical (W, y, Y, T, X, etc...), this behavior is decreased or eliminated.

Here's a sample program that illustrates this behavior:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.GlyphVector;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class FontSizeTest {
    public FontSizeTest() {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int width = 700, height = 120;

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();

        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        FontRenderContext frc = g2d.getFontRenderContext();
        Font font = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 10);
        GlyphVector gv;
        Rectangle pixelBounds;

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.translate(10, 100);

        for(float size : new float[]{40f, 80f, 120f}) {
            font = font.deriveFont(size);
            gv = font.createGlyphVector(frc, "Hello World");
            pixelBounds = gv.getPixelBounds(frc, 0, 0);
            System.out.printf("font: %s%npixel bounds: %s%n", font, pixelBounds);
            g2d.fill(gv.getOutline());
            g2d.draw(pixelBounds);
        }

        g2d.dispose();

        File pngFile = new File("FontSizeTest.png");
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", pngFile);
        System.out.printf("png file written: %s%n", pngFile.getCanonicalPath());
    }
}
```

The output of this program is info to the console:

```
font: java.awt.Font[family=SansSerif,name=SansSerif,style=plain,size=40]
pixel bounds: java.awt.Rectangle[x=4,y=-31,width=217,height=31]
font: java.awt.Font[family=SansSerif,name=SansSerif,style=plain,size=80]
pixel bounds: java.awt.Rectangle[x=7,y=-62,width=432,height=63]
font: java.awt.Font[family=SansSerif,name=SansSerif,style=plain,size=120]
pixel bounds: java.awt.Rectangle[x=11,y=-93,width=651,height=94]
png file written: FontSizeTest.png
```

And the image:

[image: Output of FontSizeTest]

Note how the larger font sizes draw offset from the smaller font sizes.

If this is expected behavior, I can adjust for it by getting the offset from the pixel bounds and adjusting the x coordinate using `translate`; I'm just not sure this is the expected behavior.  I feel like I'm doing something wrong - missing some piece of the `Graphics2D` programming approach.

Comment: Have you tried different fonts?  It's possible that the characters have a "leading" space

Comment: @MadProgrammer I ran through all of the fonts on my system, and they all have some level of offset as the sizes increase.  You can see the snippet of code I used here: [Pastie URL](http://pastie.org/10624244).  I'm suspecting at this point that the offset is built in and that I'll just have to adjust the layout to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This effect is normal behaviour of Fonts. Even Microsoft Word has this offset in textlines with different sizes.
[image: As you can see here!]

If you want to align all of your textlines at the same pixel line you could use `translate` with your calculated pixel bounds as you mentioned.
A way more elegant way is to shift your glyphs positions in the GlyphVector. That will also result in a shift of the `getPixelBounds` result.

```
public static void adjust(GlyphVector gv){
    // calc the adjust Factor
    int adjust = (int)Math.round(gv.getGlyphVisualBounds(0).getBounds2D().getMinX());
    // Shift all the Glyphs in Vector
    for (int i = 0; i < gv.getNumGlyphs(); i++) {
        Point2D point = gv.getGlyphPosition(i);
        gv.setGlyphPosition( i, new Point2D.Double(
            point.getX() - adjust, 
            point.getY()));         
    }
}
```

Use it in your code after you create the Glyph Vector and you get the result you want.

```
gv = font.createGlyphVector(frc, "Hello World");
adjust(gv);
```

Comment: Excellent answer, @ArcticLord.  I had already come to the conclusion that it was expected behavior, but your corroborating evidence from Word is helpful, and your suggestion + example of adjusting the glyph position instead of using `translate` really appeals to my aesthetic sense. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=java.awt.Graphics2D) may not directly answer your question. But it has a lot of examples about Graphics2D.

Comment: And thus, should be comment, unless you want to expand on the relevant content, so should the link go dead, the answer doesn't become less irrelevant then it already is. From the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) - *"Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."*

Comment: Well, that is a lot of examples.  Thanks @Ryan; I've looked through a lot of them and not seen any help for my particular situation, but I haven't gone through them all (there are 109 instances of "font"). :-)